# Create and distribute ssh-keys using ansible

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

Using an ansible playbook, I need to create a ssh-key with the name 'mykey' for each host in the group 'client'.

After that I need to add this generated ssh-key (the public key, of course) to the one `authorized_keys` file of one user of one host 'server'.

I know how to generate ssh-keys with ansible, and I know how to add one to the `authorized_keys` file, but I do not know to add keys of many clients to the `authorized_keys` file of one server. Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: If you know how to do it for one key, and you have a list of client keys then you can just loop the task for each key https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, using the `register` and `delegate_to` options.

Here is a snippet of my playbook:

```
- hosts:
    - myclients

  - name: Create ssh-client-keypair for each client
    openssh_keypair:
      path: /root/.ssh/myid
      comment: {{ inventory_hostname }}
      type: ed25519
      state: present
    register: generated_key

  - name: Add ssh-public-key to (single) server
    ansible.posix.authorized_key:
      user: root
      key: "{{ generated_key.public_key }}"
      comment: "{{ generated_key.comment }}"
      state: present
    delegate_to: myserver
```